# What can replace milk, for vegan pancakes without eggs?

Tags: veganism, dairy-substitutes, recipe-request

Please see the question in the title. My goal is to make vegan pancakes without:

1. eggs,
2. milk,
3. any milk alternative that uses [Natural Flavours](https://empoweredsustenance.com/non-dairy-milks/), like soy or coconut milk.

I live in Ontario, Canada and visited these 6 stores, yet all their soy and coconut milks contain Natural Flavours: Loblaws, Longo's,  Metro,  [Noah's Natural Foods](https://www.blogto.com/grocery/noahs/), Whole Foods Market, [Your Good Health](https://www.yourgoodhealth.com/#locations).

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're looking for soy or coconut milk without additives, or anything that would replace milk in pancakes... Can you clarify on exactly what you want?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you may wanna give **oat milk** a shot.
Since you seem particular about what contents you want in it as well as what general location you wanna buy it in, I will suggest making it yourself, as it is **quick**, **easy**, and **cheap** to do so. Not to mention, you will end up with a product consisting entirely of water and oats (+whatever optional sweetener you may wanna add).

It takes mere minutes of effort:

**Ingredients**

1. 1 cup rolled oats (100 g)
2. 3-4 cups water (750 ml – 1 l),
   depending on how thick you like your milk

**Instructions**

1. Soak the oats in water for at least 30 minutes. We usually soak them
   overnight, but it’s not necessary.
2. Drain the oats and wash them (discard the soaking water).
3. Blend the oats with 3 to 4 cups of clean water (750 ml to 1 liter).
4. Strain the milk using a cheesecloth, a strainer, a napkin or a nut
   milk bag.
5. Store in a sealed container in the fridge for up to 5 days.

The above guide is taken from the first result on Google for "How to make oat milk". [The article](https://simpleveganblog.com/how-to-make-oat-milk/) contains a few more tips worth reading. Substitute with any other recipe if you'd like, this is merely a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. I'll need revisit these supermarkets to see if their Oat Milk contains Natural Flavours.

Comment: How does oat milk compare to dairy in terms of pH? I've encountered [problems with some non-dairy milks in pancakes](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/550/70) (tl;dr they rise fine with soy milk, but poorly with almond milk, because they interact differently with baking soda)

Answer (score 3):

I have been told by more kitchen-savvy friends that aqua-faba is an effective replacement for egg in baking.

Aqua faba is essentially the runoff from tinned chickpeas and you can easily just use that directly, or there are suppliers that sell a more refined version.

I can't speak for it myself, but having tried cakes baked using it, they've been consistently fluffy and delicious without any hint of chickpea in the flavour.

Answer (score 0):

Simple recipe for vegan pancakes (I’m from UK where pancakes are similar to crepes which may be different to the kind of pancakes you want to make):

Ingredients:

- Unflavoured soy milk;
- White flour
- Vegetable oil (for frying)

Method:

1. Mix into a smooth batter
2. Let it stand for ten minutes
3. Use like you would use egg-based pancake mix (frying pan, small amount of oil hot, flip half way through)

After a few tries you’ll get the hang of how thick/thin to make the batter mix. It thickens a little during the standing phase.

I usually have these with sugar/lemon juice, or with maple syrup. Sometimes ice cream and/or chocolate sauce.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Vegetarianism SE. Since you are providing a recipe, I guess it could be nice to also have some quantities/ratios mentioned? Like how much flour for how much soy milk do you tend to use? Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @AlexanderRossa  - thanks for the welcome. Regarding the quantities/ratios I don’t usually consider this when mixing the batter, it’s more a matter of observation and experience but next time I make it I will be mindful of this and measure some quantities so I can report back here and update my post.

Comment: I completely understand that, I myself use a similar methodology :). And that's very kind of you, thanks.